# Cells(1) - what does it mean

Tags: excel, vba

I recieved an answer in the code below from a very helpful stackoverflow user:
[Solving variable variable's names issue in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334447/solving-variable-variables-names-issue-in-excel)

But I am not sure why he uses Cells(1) in the code. Does this correspond to: 
Cells(1) = whole worksheet?

Thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write a simple Macro to see what it does. Something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To 5
Debug.Print Cells(c).Address
Next
End Sub
```

You would then see, that Cells(1) refers to A1, Cells(2) to B1 and so on.

Comment: Thx a lot for an idea.

Comment: I just had another look at the code from the answer from your previous question, and there he defines a function `InitialiseQuestion` which has a number of input arguments. Most of these arguments are Ranges. Calling Cells(1) on these ranges will then retrieve the first range stored in these ranges, Cells(2)  the second and so on. Since in my example the Ranges used is the whole worksheet, the first range retrieved is A1, the second B1 and so on, since excel reads from left to right and from top to bottom.

Comment: Ok, it will help me with understanding the code, so thx a lot.